# Emeditor error "There is not enough space on the disk" - how to I configure where temporary files are stored

Tags: emeditor

I used EmEditor to do a find and replace in a very large 100GB file, when I try to save it it says "there is not enough space on the disk".

I assume its talking about C:, the file i;m editing is located on D: and there is 757GB free there.

Is there an option I can change to set where temporary files are stored in EmEditor, so I can set it not to use the C:.  Some people have said its under Tools > Customize, but I can't see it there

Answer (score 0):

[settings_for_memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2Tll.png)

Use the latest Version, since 22.2 there are new settings.
[download-incl-beta](https://support.emeditor.com/en/downloads) and
[technica_review](https://www.emeditor.com/emeditor-core/emeditor-v22-2-0-released-including-technical-review/)

Comment: For the Customize dialog window/pop up I only have Notifications, Update & Language listed in the left hand panel, there is no Advanced. It is version 22.2.0

Comment: @Paul Please go on Menu "Tools > All Commands: Tools > Customize > Advanced" or copy "editor.ExecuteCommandByID(9046);" to your clipboard (without "), go to Menu "Macros > Run Clipboard" it should open the dialog. Do you use EmEditor Professional?

Comment: Its EmEditor free edition, I guess thats why the option isn't available. There is no Macros > run clipboard option and doing your first suggestion just opens the dialog box I had open before but the Advanced page isn't listed down the left hand side

Comment: I don't want to downgrade my version to see what's missing in the free version.
I have bought and tested several editors in my computer life (private and at work). Of course also those that cost nothing. Notepad++ has a large community where you can also find one or the other on the internet, but this is no comparison to EmEditor. I use the editor for very small to very large files. The speed advantage of EmEditor over notepad++ and ultimately the failure to open large files was a clear choice. Also another widely used commercial editor (still own a license) does not have the performance.

Comment: I had also used editors in parallel for a long time because some have builtin features that others lack. But in the meantime EmEditor has so many unique features that no other editor under windows can keep up. At least after I started to use macros and javascript to customize EmEditor to my needs, there are no more changes. As soon as I come to new or recurring work steps, I already think about whether I make a new macro here. As a beginner, you can't imagine what possibilities you have "out of the box", the possibilities with macros are then a multiplier.

Comment: Many words, but who works so long with computers and is always looking for optimization, regret not a single day the purchase of several EmEditor Professional licenses (Lifetime!!!)